# Apache rewrite rule is not taking effect after restart

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, configuration, apache2, vhosts

I have these in my Apache vhost

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^highlight=WyJwb3J0YWwiLCJub3RpY2VzIiwicG9ydGFsIG5vdGljZXMiXQ==(&.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^component/k2/item/473-careers-portal-notices\.html$ /career-portal-notices.html?%1 [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

However, when I hit `site.com/component/k2/item/473-careers-portal-notices.html?highlight=WyJwb3J0YWwiLCJub3RpY2VzIiwicG9ydGFsIG5vdGljZXMiXQ==` I do not get redirected to `/carerr-portal-notices.html`.

What do I need to change to make this redirection happen?  And I've restarted Apache already.

Comment: Have you tried removing the leading ^ and the $ at the end, and then also the "(&.*)" ?

Comment: I just tried this.  Nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Joomla site.  Apparently the .htaccess file that comes with Joomla can override any rewrite rules you place in the vhost.